# Printing to linux server from Unix application

Tags: lubuntu, printing

I am trying to print to a cups server on a ubuntu cups server and it will not recognize any job. I can ping the unix server that hosts the application, but I am unable to receive any print job from the unix application to the linux server. What can I do to make this work?

Comment: Is the Ubuntu CUPS server configured to "Share printers connected to this system" and "Allow printing from the Internet"? Start by reading the CUPS logs in `/var/log/cups` (on the Ubuntu system).